# Fluctuation in bounding box with live feed

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, camera

I'm detecting object from a live feed of a camera. The backend model used is ssd_mobilenet_v2. If I capture a image and feed it to the model for 10 times; everytime I get the bounding box of same size. But when I feed a live video to the model (without changing anything in the frame), with every frame I'm getting bouding box of different size (variation of 4 to 5 pixels when the image resolution is 640x480). The reason which I think behind is that due to tiny variations in the digital camera sensors, no two frames will be 100% the same — some pixels will most certainly have different intensity values [1](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/05/25/basic-motion-detection-and-tracking-with-python-and-opencv/). In this [link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/05/25/basic-motion-detection-and-tracking-with-python-and-opencv/) the user have used GaussianBlur to average pixel intensities across an 21 x 21 region. Is this the only way to fix this ? Or there any better way to correct this.

I'm using Raspberry camera to get the video feed.

1. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/05/25/basic-motion-detection-and-tracking-with-python-and-opencv/

Comment: What is the input size of your model?

Comment: @AlexCohn It's 600x600.